Select child less
I'm new to less and not yet familiar with the syntax. I want to perform this selection in less. Here is how it looks in css:
.checkout-payment-method .payment-method-content>.actions-toolbar>.primary .action.primary

Can someone give me a solution?
Many thanks in advance.

if you are not familiar with the syntax you can always start with their getting started or use an online css to less converter

I’m voting to close this question because it is too simple and not worth answering
